# How to get a file upload time via API?

Tags: palantir-foundry, palantir-foundry-api

I need to get a timestamp, when the dataset was updated with a fresh new data.

Users upload their Excel and binary files to separate datasets via Plantir Foundry interface using drag and drop. I have ~120 datasets to check (60 Excel files are parsed by Foundry automatically and 60 binary files are parsed via transform). I do not want to configure health checks for large number of datasets manually, so I need to use REST API.

I have tried to call GET requests to `https://..palantir_foundry_root.../compass/api/resources/...my_dataset_rid` however the responses for uploaded files does not contain correct update time (the key `['modified']['time']` from the response).

What API call should I use to get the correct file upload time?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get file specific timestamp you should use this endpoint:
`https://<palantir_root>/foundry-catalog/api/catalog/datasets/<dataset_rid>/views2/<branch_name>/files`.

Each file will have it's own `timeModifed` timestamp. Make sure to check which time zone the responses are in.